# Check if Assets Field Contains File of Type

Tags: templating, assets

What’s the best way to check if an assets field contains a file of a certain type?

Something to the effect of: `if assetsField.contains.file-of-type('image')`

Answer (score 2):

See `kind` in the docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel

I haven't tried it but I suspect it's something like this:

```
{% set file = assetsField.first %}
{% if file.kind == 'image' %}
  // blah blah
{% endif %}
```

There's also `extension` but kind is probably better here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the model’s `kind` property mentioned in the other answer, there is also a `kind` parameter for asset criteria models.

```
{% set containsVid = assetsField.kind('video').total() > 0 %}
```